# Why isn't $y=(x^6)^{1/3}$ a polynomial function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, polynomials

I've been told that $y=(x^6)^{1/3}$ isn't a polynomial function because of the radical but I believe that the equation could be simplified to $y=x^2$ which fits the definition of a polynomial function.

Comment: so @Daniel actual problem is :is your believe correct or other assumption? :D it is just for  funy

Comment: Perhaps you can ask the person who told you this what it means for two functions to be equal, e.g. the meaning of $f=g$ when $f:{\mathbb R} \rightarrow {\mathbb R}$ and $g:{\mathbb R} \rightarrow {\mathbb R}$ are two given functions from the reals to the reals, and whether "polynomial" is a property that is invariant under equality of functions.

Comment: Who has told you $x\mapsto (x^6)^{1/3}$ is not a polynomial function? For real numbers, it is identical to $x\mapsto x^2$.

Comment: Are you sure they said polynomial *function* and not polynomial *expression* or polynomial *form*? If the latter, then it is a distinction between *syntax* (language) and *semantics* (meaning, denotation).

Answer (score 3):

Raising to non integer exponents poses some problems. One *might* define $x^{1/3}$ also for negative values of $x$, because this is essentially the cubic root; but while $\sqrt[3]{x}$ is non ambiguous, a fraction doesn't change according to its representation:
$$
\frac{1}{3}=\frac{2}{6},
$$
but writing $x^{1/3}=x^{2/6}$ at least raises some doubts.

My personal opinion is that powers with non integer exponents should always be bound to positive values of the base, thus making algebraic manipulations possible without restrictions. So, if we bind $x$ to be positive, we have the *true* identities
$$
x^{1/3}=x^{2/6}=(x^2)^{1/6}=(x^{1/6})^2,
$$
which would be plainly false if $x<0$ were allowed.

I acknowledge that others don't think this way and define $x^{p/q}$ ($p$ and $q$ integers, $q\ne0$) also for negative values of $x$ provided $p$ and $q$ are coprime and $q$ is odd.

What's the convention used in a textbook should be clearly expressed from the beginning. There is no law cast in the stone about this (and most of mathematics, either). Different fields of math use different conventions; just think to the concept of function itself: in several fields functions *must* have a well defined domain and codomain, while in Analysis this is not strictly enforced. It's not a problem, provided one is made aware of the convention used.

In your case there is *no* doubt: the function $x\mapsto(x^6)^{1/3}$ assumes, for every real $x$, the same value as the function $x\mapsto x^2$. Thus the two functions are equal and, being $x\mapsto x^2$ clearly a polynomial function, the conclusion is obvious.

On the other hand, $x\mapsto(x^2)^{1/2}$ is *not* a polynomial function, because it is the same as $x\mapsto|x|$ and there's no polynomial form of this function: polynomial functions are everywhere differentiable, $x\mapsto|x|$ is not differentiable at $0$.

Comment: Let $\,f\,$ be you favorite hairy transcendental function that is invertible. Maybe so hairy that it is not even provable that $\,f\,$ is total or invertible without using very strong set-theoretic axioms. Then do you consider $\,f^{-1}\! f(x)\,$ to be a polynomial function of $\,x\,?\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque If I don't *prove* that $f^{-1}$ exists, I'm not allowed to use it; if I know it exists, then $f^{-1}\circ f$ is the identity by definition. What “exists” mean can be object of a discussion. In any case, the function under examination is polynomial; for other functions I might say “I don't know”.

Answer (score 0):

sAt least in $\mathbb{C}$ the functions $f(x) := (x^6)^\frac{1}{3}$ and $g(x) := x^2$ are not equal, as $f(\sqrt[3]{i}) = (i^2)^\frac{1}{3} = -1$ and $g(\sqrt[3]{i}) \not\in \mathbb{R}$.

**Edit:** Oops. As the comments stare $f$ is not well defined in $\mathbb{C}$, so my answer does not work out so easy. Sorry

Comment: Over $\mathbb{C}$ the function is not even defined, as  the cubic root isn't a function (at least in the usual sense of “one valued functions”).

Comment: For complex numbers, $(i^2)^{\frac{1}{3}} = (-1)^{\frac{1}{3}}$ has multiple values.

Comment: There are three (entire) branches of $\left(z^6\right)^{1/3}$. They are $z \mapsto \omega^k\cdot z^2$ with $\omega\neq 1$ a third root of unity and $k\in \{0,1,2\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Salman Khan talks about that in one of his (many) videos.
It's at the beginning of this video:
[About polynomials](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra/multiplying-factoring-expression/polynomial_basics/v/addition-and-subtraction-of-polynomials)
Hope it helps you understanding polynomials.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to be a little pedantic (but that's my job).

I want to distinguish between a *function* and the way that the function is specified. The functions
$$
f_1 : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R: x \mapsto x \\ 
f_2 : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R: x \mapsto (x+1) - 1
$$
are identical as *functions* (they have the same domain, codomain, and relation), but they've been *specified* differently.

Most often, we see functions specified by relatively simple *expressions*, i.e., strings of characters that we recognize as syntactically correct and semantically valid stuff. But sometimes they're specified by tables, or by "cases" (one expression gets used for $x > 2$, another for $x \le 2$, for instance), etc.

Certain expressions are called "polynomials in $x$"; they consist of a finite sum of *terms*, each term being either (a) a constant, or (b) the product of a constant (which may be omitted if it's $1$) and a positive integer power of $x$. Terms where the constant is negative can have an "addition" replaced by a subtraction, so that $4 + -2x^2$ can be written $4 - 2x^2$.

The expression $(x^6)^{\frac{1}{3}}$ doesn't meet the criteria for being a polynomial. The expression $x^2$ does meet the criteria. If I had been the one talking to you about this thing (which would have meant that I was in a very formal mood), I would have said "The function description $y = (x^6)^\frac{1}{3}$ does not define the function via a polynomial expression. It is, however, identical, as a function, to one that can be defined via a polynomial expression."

In practice, this almost never matters.

We tend to be sloppy and say that the function "isn't polynomial" when we mean that the description's not a polynomial, and everyone kinda gets it, and we move on. In the same way, we sometimes say "The vector $v$ is a linear combination of the vectors $x_1$ and $x_2$." What we really mean is that there's a linear-combination-expression whose value happens to be $v$, but the distinction almost never matters in much of mathematics. I'm guessing that in logic and formal semantics, it matters quite a lot, but those aren't my areas, so I cannot say.